# What's Python's equivalent to Java InputStream's available method?

Tags: java, python, sockets

Java's InputStream provides a method named `available` which returns the number of bytes that can be read without blocking.

How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: Can you explain why you need this information? It is not, well, available.

Answer (score 3):

You've got to tell us what type of object you're working with.  I'm assuming you're talking about a socket read.  Either you read the socket with blocking or you read without blocking.  You can measure how you have just read in a non-blocking read, if you are interested in that.  However, it sounds like you are trying to bend python into a java.io style stream-buffer paradigm that it just doesn't support in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427) will help.

Or [that link](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/non-blocking-console-io-is-not-possible/).

To summarize, you could use [select](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-select.html), which works for sockets in Windows and for sockets and other files (and pipes) in UNIX.

Comment: I knew about select, but I thought there was another way :)

Comment: Maybe you should add that information to your question the next time?